# Why are there no two steps involved in this following reaction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, hydrocarbons

I was studying the chemical properties of alkynes in which I found the following reaction with alcohols

> Ethyne gas reacts with methanol to form methyl vinyl ether.
> $$\ce{H-C≡C-H + CH3OH -> CH2=CH-OCH3}$$

Now I was quite surprised at seeing this reaction as in most of the other reactions(such as [addition of acetic acid to ethyne](https://www.vedantu.com/question-answer/the-final-product-formed-by-ethyne-and-acetic-class-11-chemistry-cbse-5fb0a47d1a589d7d2600d811)). The electrophilic addition process was taking place twice. What I think is that $\ce{OCH3}$ must be a +M group (because of lone pairs on Oxygen atom, I suppose) and as a result the pi bond between the carbon atoms in methyl vinyl ether should break in the following way:

> [image]

and then undergo another electrophilic addition reaction to form 1,1-dimethoxyethane (IUPAC nomenclature). Where am I wrong?

Comment: Under what conditions is this reaction reported to take place?

Comment: I checked my notes and I found out that I havent written the condition for this reaction to proceed... neither did our teacher tell us the conditions under which this reaction has to be perfomed-as far as I can remember

Comment: According to the literature this is done at high temperature and pressure in the presence of a basic metal catalyst and may be a radical process. It is certainly a high energy surface process and those are difficult to be precise about the mechanism.  see https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2016/ra/c5ra25100a